# Qt выравнивание лэйаутов

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, как выравнять 2 lineedit'a чтобы они начинались с одного места?
На данный момент формочка формируется так:

```
QHBoxLayout* hl1 = new QHBoxLayout();
hl1->addWidget(m_l_label);
hl1->addWidget(m_e_login);

QHBoxLayout* hl2 = new QHBoxLayout();
hl2->addWidget(m_l_password);
hl2->addWidget(m_e_password);

QHBoxLayout* hl3 = new QHBoxLayout();
hl3->addWidget(m_btn_login);
hl3->addWidget(m_btn_cancel);

QVBoxLayout* vl1 = new QVBoxLayout();
vl1->addItem(hl1);
vl1->addItem(hl2);
vl1->addItem(hl3);
vl1->addWidget(m_b_remember);
vl1->addWidget(m_l_forgot);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD (решение, спасибо @BeardedBeaver), заодно поможет избавиться от паразитных лейблов:

```
QFormLayout* fl1 = new QFormLayout();
fl1->addRow(tr("Login:"), m_e_login);
fl1->addRow(tr("Password:"), m_e_password);
fl1->setSpacing(3);

QHBoxLayout* hl1 = new QHBoxLayout();
hl1->addWidget(m_btn_login);
hl1->addWidget(m_btn_cancel);

QVBoxLayout* vl1 = new QVBoxLayout();
vl1->addItem(fl1);
vl1->addItem(hl1);
vl1->addWidget(m_b_remember);
vl1->addWidget(m_l_forgot);

setLayout(vl1);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте gridlayout или formlayout

Comment: CTRL + G попробуйте

Comment: @SЌĬPクラス, файлы с формочками создаются на основе json-шаблонов генератором написанным на питоне, где именно нажать?)

Comment: задайте минимальный размер вашим лэйбам. Правда, конечно это может превратиться в проблему, если увеличить текст в одной из них выше предела при отсутствии политики размеров. Так что лучше всего QGridLayout

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, думал об этом, пока больше всего понравился вариант с QFormLayout (про который я не знал)